# poner un enlace <a> en un echo

Tags: php

Buen día,

Resulta que en un archivo .php recibo una peticion por medio de ajax para luego rellenar una tabla en otro archivo con los registros encontrados de acuerdo al parametro, todo funciona de maravilla. Antes que todo, esto es importante, mi archivo .php el cual hace la consulta y rellena la tabla esta una ruta fija por ejemplo: `misitio.com/consultas/consultar_datos.php`

En un campo de la consulta tengo la ruta de una foto que el usuario subió con anterioridad por medio de otro script la cual viene siendo por ejemplo: `misitio.com/uploads/foto13.jpg`

lo que quiero es que al momento de llenar la tabla que como digo todo funciona correctamente, al poner en la celda el enlace, pueda colocar una etiqueta  que diga ver foto y así me abra la imagen, el problema esta en que el enlace queda de la siguiente manera: `misitio.com/consultas/misitio.com/uploads/foto13.jpg`

es decir, me toma la carpeta en la que esta el archivo .php, y lo concatena con el enlace que esta en el campo mysql: `misitio.com/consultas  +  misitio.com/uploads/foto13.jpg`

aqui el codigo del archivo php completo:

```
<?php
include '../PHP/conectar.php';

//hago la consulta
$result = mysqli_query($conexion,"select * from solicitudes WHERE estado='Solicitado' and tipo_solicitud='revision_tecnica'");

echo "<table>
<tr>
  <th align='center'>Nombre</th>
  <th align='center'>Comentarios</th>
  <th align='center'>Foto</th>
</tr>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
  echo "<tr>";     
    echo "<td align='center'>" . $row['nombre'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td align='center'>".$row['comentarios']."</td>";      

    //aqui es donde esta mal
    $ruta=$row['ruta_foto'];
    echo "<td align='center'><a href='$ruta'>Ver foto</a></td>";

    //ya he intentado asi
    //echo "<td align='center'><a href='".$ruta."'>Ver foto</a></td>";

    //tambien intenté asi, sin guardar en variable
    //echo "<td align='center'><a href='$row['ruta_foto']'>Ver foto</a></td>";

  echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
mysqli_close($conexion);
?>
```

por si se preguntan, ya comprobé que en mySql si esta guardado el enlace bien, es decir `misitio.com/uploads/foto13.jpg` para el ejemplo

alguna idea?

Gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que necesitas concatenarle una `/` antes de poner tu link de la siguiente manera:

**PHP**:

```
echo '<td align="center"><a href="/'.$ruta.'">Ver foto</a></td>';
```

Inverti las comillas para que fuera mas facil entenderlo y acomodarlo, lo que paso con eso es que sin la **diagonal** le dices que la ruta esta después de tu ruta actual y **anteponiendo la diagonal** le dices que va a ser una **ruta totalmente nueva**.

Igual si no te funciona con **1 diagonal** puedes probar concatenando **2 diagonales** de la siguiente forma:

**PHP:**

```
echo '<td align="center"><a href="//'.$ruta.'">Ver foto</a></td>';
```

Saludos!

Comment: Perfecto, es lo que faltaba, gracias hermano!

Comment: Califica con flechita verde :) por nada!

Answer (score 0):

Podrías intentar NO guardar el dominio en tu ruta del archivo, así quedaría guardado en la DB como `/uploads/foto13.jpg` en lugar de `misitio.com/uploads/foto13.jpg`

luego en el retorno del `<a>` dejar la ruta que tienes actualmente, quedando como

```
echo "<td align='center'><a href=".$row['ruta_foto'].">Ver foto</a></td>";
```

Eso debería resultar en algo como

```
<td align='center'><a href='/uploads/foto13.jpg'>Ver foto</a></td>
```

Que el navegador interpretaría como

```
<td align='center'><a href='misitio.com/consultas/misitio.com/uploads/foto13.jpg'>Ver foto</a></td>
```